# Multiple AddToShipoutPicture

Tags: backgrounds, eso-pic

`\myTileWallPaper` is defined in the classfile like this

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myTileWallPaper}[4]{%
\begingroup
\setlength{\tileYoffset}{\wpYoffset}
\setlength{\tilewidth}{#1}%
\setlength{\tileheight}{#2}%
\setlength{\tileY}{0pt}%
\whiledo{\lengthtest{\tileY < \paperheight}}{% 
  \setlength{\tileX}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\tileXoffset}{\wpXoffset}%
  \whiledo{\lengthtest{\tileX < \paperwidth}}{% 
    \put(\LenToUnit{\tileXoffset},\LenToUnit{\tileYoffset}){%
      \includegraphics[height=\tileheight,width=\tilewidth]{#3}}%
    \addtolength{\tileX}{\tilewidth}
    \addtolength{\tileXoffset}{\tilewidth}
  }%
  \addtolength{\tileY}{\tileheight}
  \addtolength{\tileYoffset}{\tileheight}
}%
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

When I use two `\AddToShipoutPicture`s, LaTeX throws an error.

```
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}% Wenn ungerade Seitenzahl, dann Bild 1, sonst Bild 2.
    {\myTileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{wallpaper1}}% ungerade Seite
    {\myTileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{wallpaper2}}% gerade Seite
}
    \AddToShipoutPicture{\setlength{\unitlength{0.1mm}}\put(500,2522){\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{Logoimg}}}
```

The error is as follows :

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
{
l.73 \end{document}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

If I remove the 2nd `\AddToShipoutPicture`, everything seems to work fine.
If I remove the 2nd `\AddToShipoutPicture` and put it ahead of the first one, everything seems to work fine -- although it doesn't work since the wall-paper then covers the logo.

Comment: You have left many things undefined. Eg, you say `\setlength` with no length defined for an assignment to occur. You may consider using some other wallpaper packages (see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=watermark).

Answer (score 1):

The following tiling isn't exactly correct, but it is precisely what you would have had if your code compiled. Use, eg, *xwatermark* package instead.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\cptnewdimens{tileXoffset,tileYoffset,wpXoffset,wpYoffset,
  tilewidth,tileheight,tileX,tileY}
\wpXoffset.25cm\wpYoffset.25cm
\robust@def*\myTileWallPaper#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \tileYoffset\wpYoffset
  \tilewidth=\dimexpr#1\relax
  \tileheight=\dimexpr#2\relax
  \tileY=0pt
  \cptwhiledim\tileY<\paperheight\do{%
    \tileX=0pt \tileXoffset\wpXoffset
    \cptwhiledim\tileX<\paperwidth\do{%
      \put(\LenToUnit{\tileXoffset},\LenToUnit{\tileYoffset}){%
        \includegraphics[height=\tileheight,width=\tilewidth]{#3}%
      }%
      \addtolength{\tileX}{\tilewidth}%
      \addtolength{\tileXoffset}{\tilewidth}%
    }%
    \addtolength{\tileY}{\tileheight}%
    \addtolength{\tileYoffset}{\tileheight}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \ifnumoddTF\thepage
    {\myTileWallPaper{.25\paperwidth}{.25\paperheight}{diag1.eps}}%
    {\myTileWallPaper{.25\paperwidth}{.25\paperheight}{diag2.eps}}%
}
```

Here is the correct solution. Now you use keys in place of parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture,graphicx,ifpdf}
\usepackage{pathkeys}
\makeatletter
\pathkeys{wallpaper/asif/define*(cmd):
  viewport/00 00 100 100;
  xtilenr/2;
  ytilenr/2;
  wpxoffset/0pt;
  wpyoffset/0pt;
  inputpath//;
}
\newcommand*\mytilewallpaper[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pathkeys@currentpath{wallpaper/asif}%
  \pathkeys{set:#1}%
  \pathkeys@useshortcmds
  \edef\ffileext{\ifpdf pdf\else eps\fi}%
  \edef\reserved@a{\pkv{inputpath}}%
  \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\ltxkeys@stripallouterbraces
    \expandafter{\reserved@a}}%
  \edef\Ginput@path{\ifcsnullTF\reserved@a{}{{\reserved@a/}}}%
  \cptdimdef\tilewidth{(\paperwidth-\pkv{wpxoffset}*2)/\pkv{xtilenr}}%
  \cptdimdef\tileheight{(\paperheight-\pkv{wpyoffset}*2)/\pkv{ytilenr}}%
  \cptdimdef\tileY{-\paperheight+\pkv{wpyoffset}}%
  \@tempcntb\z@
  \cptwhilenum\@tempcntb<\pkv{ytilenr}\do{%
    \edef\tileX{\pkv{wpxoffset}}%
    \@tempcnta\z@
    \cptwhilenum\@tempcnta<\pkv{xtilenr}\do{%
      \leavevmode\@killglue
      \cptexpanded{\noexpand\put(\tileX,\tileY){\noexpand\includegraphics
      [viewport=\pkv{viewport},height=\tileheight,
      width=\tilewidth,clip]{#2.\ffileext}}}%
      \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
      \cptdimadd\tileX{\tilewidth}%
    }%
    \advance\@tempcntb\@ne
    \cptdimadd\tileY{\tileheight}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\wpspec{[viewport=20 21 590 400,xtilenr=4,ytilenr=4,
  wpxoffset=2cm,wpyoffset=2cm,inputpath={./graphics}]{comet1}}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \ifnumoddTF\thepage
    {}%
    {\expandafter\mytilewallpaper\wpspec}%
}}
x
\newpage
x
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Musa for your efforts and patience. I had problems compiling the first code. I am jus checking the 2nd code. Coming back to my initial issue.. I didn't have problem with the wallpaper part of my code -- it was only when i added the 2nd AddToShipoutPicture for providing the logo at the left hand corner of the page, did i run into all the issues. \newline I actually am looking to learn tex/Latex a bit more indepth, not just having a solution , so I was curious about why Latex threw an error message . \newline I would anyway go ahead and test the new. Thanks once again for  your patience.

Comment: The code doesn't compile at --> \pathkeys{wallpaper/asif/define*: .. The error is Package ltxkeys Error : The above keys are undefined and couldn't be set.

Comment: @Asif: Everything works fine at my end. Please update your ltxkeys package from CTAN.